# find key in dictionary with n-th largest value

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

given a dictionary like this: `example_dict ={"mark":13, "steve":3, "bill":6, "linus":11}`

finding the key with max value is easy using `max(example_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))` and min value using `min(example_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

What's the easiest way to find the key with the n-th largest value? e.g. the key with the 2nd largest value here is `linus`

Comment: Make a list of all the values, and find the 3rd largest. Then search the dictionary for all the keys with that value.

Comment: I suppose sorting would be the fastest way to go. At least not finding the max, delete it and search again. So I would go for the former, sort and search

Comment: Note that your codes for min and max don't work if there are duplicate values. They'll just return one of the duplicates, not all of them.

Comment: @ErikvandeVen: nope. The problem of the selection of the n-th largest element is known to be "easier" than sorting, and an O(N) worst-case-time algorithm is known.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but just out of curiosity: this only counts if there is only one n-th element you want to extract, right? And you are referring to quickselect?

Comment: @ErikvandeVen: no, QuickSelect is not worst case O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Use [nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import heapq

example_dict ={"mark":13, "steve":3, "bill":6, "linus":11}

*_, res = heapq.nlargest(2, example_dict, key=example_dict.get)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
linus
```

From the documentation:

> Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset defined by
> iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that
> is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for
> example, key=str.lower).

A note on performance, also from the documentation:

> perform best for smaller values of n. For
> larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function.
> Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and
> max() functions. If repeated usage of these functions is required,
> consider turning the iterable into an actual heap.

Note that it returns a list, that is why you discard the first `n-1` elements

Answer (score 0):

Use **QuickSelect** algorithm. It works in O(n) on average

Comment: QuickSelect, like QuickSort, runs in `O(n^2)` in the worst case

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def nth_largest_key(di, n):
    sorted_items = sorted(di.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],
                          reverse=True)
    return sorted_items[n-1][0]


input_di = {"mark":13, "steve":3, "bill":6, "linus":11}
print(nth_largest_key(input_di, int(input().strip())))
```